# How to infer ThisType<?> of a function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript 2.9.2 I'm trying to recover the declared type of `this` for a function.

Is this possible?

Here's what I've tried:

```js
// Two different ways of specifying the type of `this`.
declare function foo(this: {hello: 'world'}): any;
type baz = ThisType<{hi: 'there'}> & (()=> any);

// Attempts to recover `typeof this` for foo and baz...
type fooThisType = typeof foo extends (this: infer T) => any ? T : 'bad'; // 'bad'
type bazThisType = baz extends ThisType<infer T> ? T : 'bad'; // {}
type bazThisType1 = baz extends ThisType<infer T> & (()=>any) ? T : 'bad'; // {}

// Desired utility type...
type ThisTypeOf<T extends (...args: any[])=>any> =
    T extends (this: infer U, ...args: any[]) => any ? U : never;

// Doesn't work.
type a = ThisTypeOf<typeof foo>; // never
type b = ThisTypeOf<baz>; // {}
```

I tried the above in [TypeScript 2.8.1](https://typescript-play.js.org/?ts=2.8.1#code/PTAEBUHcHtQEwJYDMkFMBOqB2AXUkBDATwGdRolQSAHVAY2SISwHNQcALVdo28ygAacEJAQDoAUHHoAbAplBIArljo4E0LIujQAFMJIAuUAG8uMmdGMByGOhlxrAXwCUxgliIBuCTl7cAIwIAL1AAXggOEXB-AB4zBBtODFRnAD5QADJQXV0XMIyPIhcfCRBQAEEcHFQAW2ocMhxYTDpoADcMUCF-CnYo0W10bVgPOFAg4LFp338R8AGYvgi-Wj6kHVBUAA8arDgyfQHjZjRh8Bdwws9QAH4IUBsgxy9Qcutn61m+SYXouYiky2u2wB0i-1osVOXXAGXu4EeoA+BBebzAJic30CIT+JCWqAAjOEJiFgXswbj8VCsGcIBlsrl8mkipd4YjkajyhiJGUwAARVAkBCYcZKdQyBB+Hi0aaSVbcSn+ADySFiCJ25MOsvkLCMoCKAG0ALpMooZMISUBWh4a0GHAwnGldACqABpQNr0Lr3J5jZcCvqbvdnYisKhOuhSuU+dBBVhrHg7ABrOVzAjExW0FWxeXrHRpV7lMMRrETDOLZWqyYFtGmJxAA). (I'm most interested in Typescript 2.9.2.)

`fooThisType` and `a` work in [TypeScript 3.5.1](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/PTAEBUHcHtQEwJYDMkFMBOqB2AXUkBDATwGdRolQSAHVAY2SISwHNQcALVdo28ygAacEJAQDoAUHHoAbAplBIArljo4E0LIujQAFMJIAuUAG8uMmdGMByGOhlxrAXwCUxgliIBuCTl7cAIwIAL1AAXggOEXB-AB4zBBtODFRnAD5QADJQXV0XMIyPIhcfCRBQAEEcHFQAW2ocMhxYTDpoADcMUCF-CnYo0W10bVgPOFAg4LFp338R8AGYvgi-Wj6kHVBUAA8arDgyfQHjZjRh8Bdwws9QAH4IUBsgxy9Qcutn61m+SYXouYiky2u2wB0i-1osVOXXAGXu4EeoA+BBebzAJic30CIT+JCWqAAjOEJiFgXswbj8VCsGcIBlsrl8mkipd4YjkajyhiJGUwAARVAkBCYcZKdQyBB+Hi0aaSVbcSn+ADySFiCJ25MOsvkLCMoCKAG0ALpMooZMISUBWh4a0GHAwnGldACqABpQNr0Lr3J5jZcCvqbvdnYisKhOuhSuU+dBBVhrHg7ABrOVzAjExW0FWxeXrHRpV7lMMRrETDOLZWqyYFtGmJxAA). However, `bazThisType` still doesn't. Is there a way to infer the template parameter for a type involved in an intersection? (e.g. Given `T<?> & U` is it possible to recover the parameter of `T`?)

Comment: This depends on the flags and typescript version which you should add to your question as running in the playground (https://typescript-play.js.org/) with the default, fairly strict, config on 3.5.1 gave the expected results.

Comment: In 3.5.1, `fooThisType` and `a` work. I guess my question then is if there is a way for `bazThisType` to work. Is it possible to recover the template parameter of a type involved in an intersection type?

Answer (score 1):

The builtin `ThisParameterType<T>` does what you need for functions. It's very similar to the utility type that you defined

```
type ThisParameterType<T> = T extends (this: infer U, ...args: any[]) => any ? U : unknown;
type a = ThisParameterType<typeof foo> // { hello: 'world' }
```

`ThisType<T>` is not meant to define `this` in a function context, but rather in an object context. There is an example here: https://fettblog.eu/this-in-javascript-and-typescript/